# jQuery Array Value Set to Each Texbox Based on class with ID

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have `array` value and need set to each `textbox`?

```
var myArray = "M001, M002";
var ID = $(this).attr('id'); <-- get based on click
$('.getArray'+ID).val(myArray);
```

HTML

```
<div>
    M001
    <input type="hidden" class="getArray<?php echo $id; ?>"/> <-- getArrayM001

    M002
    <input type="hidden" class="getArray<?php echo $id; ?>"/> <-- getArrayM002
</div>
```

After tried above code, it always show in textbox that 2 value. It should be show to each textbox based on that class ID.

Is it possible to set it for each textbox?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear...If you are using echo $id on both classes won't they have the same class?

Comment: $id is on loop data, so it sure will have different id

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: You have an array on jQuery variable. example: M001, M002 Then How to set the value array from variable to each textbox based On class?

Comment: You are setting the class of the input with php, then when something is clicked you want that value to be set to a textbox? Or to an array?

Comment: Yes, to be set to a textbox.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your requirements exactly but does this help?

```
<div class='getArray' id='<?php echo $id; ?>'>Click me</div>

$('.getArray').click(function(){
  $('.textbox').val($(this).prop('id'))
})
```